# Accessing the "this" keyword in a React state object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, state

I have a `usestate` object, like so:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: "12345",
    getFullName():any {
      return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    },
  });


...

return (
  <button onClick={() => console.log(state.getFullName())}></button>
)
```

However, when I try to run the `getFullName` method, TypeScript throws an error:

```
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; id: string; getFullName(): any; } | (() => { firstName: string; lastName: string; id: string; getFullName(): any; })'.
```

Also, if I ignore this TS warning, I still get a `can't read property 'firstName' of undefined` error

What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: Please show us *how* you call the method

Comment: I am calling it on a button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put it into separate function, its a bad idea to access "this" in functional components

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
firstName: "John",
lastName: "Doe",
id: "12345"});

const getFullName = () => {
    return `${state.firstName} ${state.lastName}`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the function `useState`, which can accept either initialState or a function producing it:

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

To fix, extract initalState to a separate object:

```
const initialState = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: "12345",
    getFullName():string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  },
};

const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkifAL5wBmURcA5FKhowNwBQnNAriRmCk4AQTBgAFAEpcnOHDSkAzvGAlgMYCgA2AZRgoYSOAF5Z8i7WBQVAORQgkALjgAiAFIQAFiVeY5lnDaKHYOzm4AIhBIfgGWwAAmLq4AjABMAMwALACssYFwAOZIMABivNra9o7STipQaoXmgSwwvFAkcAAGACQ4MF7ASgB0NNahjtR9A0PDwRNIlF1clpT+8pRcAYokKnAA2iqGSNhKJfrHALqmiKwww7xnF0YSahpaegZGUlvyre2dAA8AD5AV4UsCABJISoQbA4I5GYbFMoVKphaSUQEAenBwICgIARrwYDBhKR8NpgGgANYmHDSUzAhTKCDaJBzCCFCSIjko8qVapIaRSSjAgAKDQocCFcDJLN2bKQOOJpNIoOxwK4lG4nCAA)

Also, consider using an IIFE for constructing the initialState:

```
const initialState = ((firstName, lastName) => ({
    firstName,
    lastName,
    id: "12345",
    getFullName():string {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
  },
}))('John', 'Doe');
```

Comment: Yes but I am still getting the TSLint error in the ```this.firstName``` like I posted above

Comment: This will not work. 
1. The function executes only on initial render, so getFullName() will be erased on the first setState
2. "this" key will anyway most likely be referring to window object and this.firstName will still be undefined